# What's the best rounding_method for Ruby Money gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

We're using Ruby's Money gem. In our application, we're also converting between currencies.

So the issue of rounding comes up when you convert between currencies. Currently we're using the Ruby's built-in [`Float#round`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round).

However, this introduces "the dangling penny" problem.

```
Money.new(500,'USD').exchange_to('EUR')
#=> #Money cents:385 currency:EUR

Money.new(500,'USD').exchange_to('EUR').exchange_to('USD')
#=> #Money cents:501 currency:USD
```

So $5.00 becomes $5.01 after converting to Euro and then back! These are the exchange rates we're using:

```
{
  "GBP_TO_USD"=>1.6,
  "USD_TO_GBP"=>0.625,
  "GBP_TO_EUR"=>1.2,
  "EUR_TO_GBP"=>0.8333333333333334,
  "EUR_TO_USD"=>1.3,
  "USD_TO_EUR"=>0.7692307692307692
}
```

Is it possible to have a rounding method to avoid this problem of an extra or missing penny?  What would that rounding method be?

Or is this a mathematically insoluble problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you round a number, the information is lost. The best solution to your problem is to stop rounding (which you should not do with money anyway) and only round when you are displaying the value somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point.  Not rounding, I think you mean storing the float value.  However, I don't think Ruby's Money gem allows fractional cent (or pence). <pre>1.9.3-p0 :011 > Money.new(999.99,'USD')
 => #<Money cents:1000 currency:USD> 
</pre>  I think I may have to solve this in the application level not in the Money gem level.

Comment: Check mark would be appreciated. Not that I really needed it, but first it shows that this is your answer and second it keeps people more motivated to answer you. As I answered I saw your accept percentage but I did it anyway. If your percentage was higher you would have gotten 3+ answers and perhaps even faster.

Comment: Not rounding is a good idea in general.  But in the context of Ruby Money gem, this doesn't seem possible as Ruby money object's accuracy is the whole cent, not fractional cent.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not actually know the money gem. But I just looked at it's documentation it does not really seem suited as a money lib if it does not support partial cents. You could try to implement the exchange algorithm yourself with [Bignum](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Bignum.html).

Answer (score 2):

The latest Ruby Money gem supports fractional cents.  This would ensure that when a money object is converted to another currency and back to itself, its value would be retained.
So there's no missing/extra cent problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world this may be less of an issue because the exchange rates of "from" and "to" will not be the inverse of each other.

On the other hand, what is the scenario that you need to convert back and forth? The only scenario I can think of is that you are summing up a bunch of Money objects in different currencies:

[1 USD, 2 EUR, 3 USD]

And this will trigger currency exchange from USD to EUR and back to USD.
If this is the case, try https://github.com/lulalala/money-collection to skip unnecessary currency exchange when summing up many Money objects.